# Add an image import button in addon

Tags: python, interface, image

I have been writing an addon that utilizes an imported image.  So far the only way to import was to to to the UV/Image Editor and import the image. Then copy the name of the imported image to a text input in my addon.  This is cumbersome and I would rather have something that looks like this:

[image]

From which I can access the image through

```
bpy.data.images[<image name here>]
```

Is this possible to do? I have only been successful in accessing the image path, but that won't work for my script.

Comment: It is supposed to happen in a panel? Do you need to limit it to a certain image format (based on file extension)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get access to the file browser in Blender by using the StringProperty with the subtype "FILE_PATH". As documented [here](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.props.html). And example of using this would be

```
file_path = StringProperty(name = "File", subtype = "FILE_PATH")
```

Then you can just use file_path like this:

```
bpy.data.images.load(file_path) #most of the time you will have to do self.file_path
```

If you need to use that image elsewhere just set all that equal to a variable.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the user to append a picture to `bpy.data.images` and do not need a reference to that image, you may add the operator `bpy.ops.image.open()` operator to a panel:

```
layout.operator("image.open")
```

If you want to call it yourself, use

```
bpy.ops.image.open('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

so the file selector shows up.

---

The widget like in your screenshot is `template_ID()`, but we can't really utilize it, as we can't create pointer properties to store a datablock reference in.